# Why doesn't Skype on HTC Wildfire function properly?

Tags: audio, skype, htc-wildfire, voip

I've tried downloading Skype on my HTC Wildfire, but the calls don't work. Every time I try to call the sound stutters and doesn't come out fluent.

I've tried it on 2 different Wildfires and got the same result on both. I have another VoIP application and it sounds fine.

Where can I find a Skype version that will work with the HTC Wildfire?

Comment: Until recently Skype had a small list of supported devices.  Obviously they branched out prematurely.

Comment: Why can't I answer this question? I have reputation greater than 10?

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid that if the official Skype app does not work then you are probably out of luck. Skype do not let third party applications use their service, so you are unlikely to find anything that works.

I suspect the issue is down to the CPU speed of the HTC Wildfire, which is only 528mhz. It's likely that the processor simply can't keep up with the demands of the application, which is why you get the stuttering, and why performance is the same on other Wildfire's.

Unfortunately you may have to stick with your other VOIP application.

Edit: There are a [lot](http://blogs.skype.com/en/2010/11/skype_now_available_on_htc_wil.html) [of](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=762893) [posts](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=796637) [on](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=801387) the Skype support forum where people are complaining of poor performance on the HTC wildfire. The Skype rep does say they are aware of it and trying to improve performance, so you may just have to wait for an update to the application sometime in the future.

Comment: Truphone app for example DOES have skype included and working, so it's not a technological problem. Sure a quick search on google will find that post. But it's not an answer. I've heard that old version of skype worked with HTC wildfire, but I couldn't confirm that or find a version that works.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is the CPU speed. The HTC Wildfire has a CPU speed of 528 MHz. The Skype app is only supported on devices with a CPU clock speed of 600MHz or greater. See the section on 'What do I need to run Skype on my Android phone?' https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10653/How-can-I-get-Skype-on-my-Android-phone

Comment: Ok, but i had an app that supported skype communication... So why can't skype support skype communication ? Are their programmers that bad ?

Comment: I am guessing that the low CPU power of the phone cannot handle the Skype compression/decompression. I think the 3rd party apps would connect to their own server which would run the manage the Skype connection and run the compression/decompression so the CPU of the phone was not an issue.